# SSH Server Fingerprint

Tags: ssh, fingerprint

I'm working on a project where I need to use SSH tunneling.
We're using a private key based authentication where we put the public key on the server and the client uses the private key in order to authenticate itself.

According to several references I found, the assumption is that the server's fingerprint is enough to authenticate the server.
I probably miss something here since I can't understand how the server can authenticate itself using the public key, unless the assumption is that the public key is also stored securely (as supposed to be with the private key).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Public key is *mathematically* paired with private key. You can read about this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) or elsewhere under keyword "asymmetric cryptography" or "Public-key cryptography".

Server can prove that he owns the private key by signing some data you post to him. You can verify the signature using public key and if it is successful, the server proved that he has the matching private part of the public key you have.